# Google API--KMZ File Not Appearing in Web Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

I am attempting to get a KMZ file to load ontop of a Google Map API and the KMZ file is not appearing. Below is my code and everything executes properly when I load the HTML--the KMZ file is just missing. I tried to minimize the size of the file by converting only one feature layer vs the entire map document to KMZ but I had the same problem.

Ideas?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Map Title, USA</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAx70-         gnDWt1nCCf_pLezTNqZfH2G_im04"></script>
<script>
function initialize() 
{
var mapProp = {
   center:new google.maps.LatLng(38.89,-77),
   zoom:12,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var kmlPath = https://sites.google.com/site/geos455assignment/data_files/assignment-4/Turi_Kristen_GEOS455_Assign4.kmz';
    var urlSuffix = (new Date).getTime().toString();

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlPath + '?' + urlSuffix );
   layer.setMap(map);
 }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>`
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1384px;height:936px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The document is too large](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=https://sites.google.com/site/geos455assignment/data_files/assignment-4/Turi_Kristen_GEOS455_Assign4.kmz):

returns a KmlStatus of "DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE":

> Kml Status:DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE

- [original link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/#size-and-complexity-restrictions-for-kml-rendering-in-google-maps) (no longer valid)
- [Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):

> **Size and Complexity Restrictions for KML Rendering in Google Maps**
>
> Google Maps currently has specific limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits:
>
> **Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any time.**

- Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)    3MB
- Maximum uncompressed KML file size    10MB
- Maximum number of Network Links   10
- Maximum number of total document-wide features    1,000

Your KML is 18.3 MB, it needs to be less than 10MB.

Your options are:

1. break your KMZ file into 2 separate files containing KML of < 10 MB
2. use a third party KMZ parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)), but that may have performance issues. [Example using geoxml3 (kmz branch) and your KMZ hosted on my server)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Turi_Kristen_GEOS455_Assign4.kmz)