# QGIS KML layer won't show up in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, kml, qgis

I've trimmed US Census shapefile data to show census blocks in just three states, by editing the attribute table.

I then color coded the states based on values in the table by changing the style in qgis.

Now I want to export the new map as a KML or GeoJson layer. However each time I've tried, the layer will not show up on the Google Maps API basemap.

I believe the API code is correct, because when I use a test kml file from online, it shows.

I've tried exporting using various attributes (no symbology, feature symbology, symbol layer symbology, wsg 84,etc). I've tried hosting the file on dropbox, and my server for my website. I've tried geojson and kml and the layer simply won't show.

The file is 300+ MB. And Inspect Element shows no console errors

When I open the file in a text editor, things seem fine. The tags look closed.

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this problem. Is there an alternative to using QGIS? How can I get the Census data as a layer on my Google API project?

Comment: what version of QGIS you use? you save the file in kml?

Comment: It's the version 2.10.1

Comment: You save the layer in KML ?

Comment: yes--right click--save as-- kml-

Comment: Have you try the kml result in google Earth for check the result?

Comment: 1. is the file publicly availabe?  2. Does it meet the [restrictions on KML in the API](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) (Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ) 3MB; Maximum uncompressed KML file size 10MB)

Comment: i just checked in Earth and it works--well the boundaries show, but they don't have the colored styles.

The file is 300MB. I did not know there were limits. It's publicly available via my drop box. I also tried with my web host server.

Comment: Check the KmlStatus of the KmlLayer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API--KMZ File Not Appearing in Web Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697046/google-api-kmz-file-not-appearing-in-web-map/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size is too large. Google Maps limits file sizes for KML layers to 10MB. I had to shrink the file size and use GeoJson instead of KML.